# Regexp_replace Bigquery match 'Jungle book, The' with 'The Jungle Book

Tags: regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I'm using `REGEXP_REPLACE` with bigquery. I'm asking whether there is a better way to use `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

My current column is determined as follows:

```
CASE WHEN UPPER(Title) CONTAINS(', THE') THEN CONCAT('THE ', regexp_replace(Title, r', THE\s*\z', r'')) ELSE UPPER(Title) end as title_s,
```

I want to replace "Jungle book, The" with  "THE JUNGLE BOOK".

Can someone provde me with a better solution please.

Comment: what makes you think that this is a bad solution?

Comment: I feel like it should be possible to do it in the `regexp_replace()` function, Therefore the `CONCAT` and `CASE WHEN` would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
regexp_replace(UPPER(Title), r'(.*), THE\s*\z', r'THE \1')  as title_s,
```

Which will Upper the title, then move the `THE` part if needed

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. Bookmarking this page.

Comment: @DanielLee Instead of bookmarking the page, you can also mark the question as a favorite by clicking on the star to the left of the question.  Favorite questions can then be accessed from your profile.